# Retrieving data from Laravel Model and generating Spatie/Icalendar

Tags: php, laravel, icalendar

[image: My code]

I'm trying to retrieve data from a model, then rewriting it to the appropriate format for the Spatie Icalendar, but then it doesn't work, because of multiple events and not only a single one.

I have tried many different solutions, but didn't find one that's working.

Please, how would you iterate over the many events in the Spatie?

Spatie Documentation: https://github.com/spatie/icalendar-generator

I would like to iterate through all the calendar events, creating an array for the spatie.

It should end up in an ICAL format, that's extractable for normal calendars.

Comment: Please add code in text format and in code blocks, makes it hard to ready and for an answer to be made you most likely have to copy paste bits to use.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of inconsistencies in the code, that i think makes it way harder than it have to be. Classes named events as properties, inconsistent naming conventions, model in plural (i know, class is a reserved keyword) etc.

Simply loop over the events and add the model data one by one to the `spatie` package.

```
$calendar = Calendar::create($iCalendar->name);

$events->each(function (Classes $event) {
    $calendar->event(Event::create($event->class_type === 1 ? 'Teoritime' : 'Køretime')
        ->startsAt($event->start_time)
        ->endsAt($event->start_time->addHour())
    )  
});

dd($calendar->get());
```

I would assume it requires an end time, so i added one hour. `start_time` on the model should be added to the `$dates` array to be casted to a `Carbon` object. Instead of doing for loops, i use the collection methods to create similar logic, read about them [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#available-methods). Which is the type that the query builder returns.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states you can add an array of events to a calendar:

> After creating your event, it should be added to a calendar. There are multiple options to do this.

Here are some examples in pseudo-code, adapt to your real objects:

Add multiple events:

```php
$caledar->event($event_1)
        ->event($event_2)
        ->event($event_99)
        ...
```

Or better yet, add an **array of events**:

```php
$events = [];

foreach(Classes::all() as $class) {
    $events[] = Event::create($class->type)->startsAt($class->start_time);
}

$calendar->event($events);
```